# Custom houdini module path

Tags: path, environment-variables, houdini

I need to store Houdini *.hda files on a network share. 
This folder needs to be sourced by all users.

Usually, for those kind of requests, I use an environment variable in `~/houdini17.0/houdini.env` like for exemple:
`HOUDINI_TEMP_DIR="/my/custom/temp/path"`

But the issue is that I can find a solution for hda/otls files.
Adding it to `HOUDINI_PATH="${HOUDINI_PATH};/my/custom/hda/path"` or `HOUDINI_OTLSCAN_PATH` doesn't work and worst, it seems to break other links since a few other houdini nodes aren't available anymore.

Can someone point me to the right environnement variables?

Comment: Have you tried simply placing your otls under a sub-folder to HOUDINI_PATH called hda, as in HOUDINI_PATH/hda ? That is one of the default search locations for site-wide deployments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using $HSITE and/or $JOB environment variables.  Houdini will scan sub folders of the paths defined by $HSITE and $JOB for all relevant files and folders so you don't need to set a bunch of different env vars.  You can mirror the folder structure found in C:\Users\username\Documents\houdini16.5

Obviously replace the Houdini version with yours.  Also note that $HSITE needs to point the the folder that contains the houdini16.5 folder not the folder itself.  This way you can support multiple houdini versions with a single env var.

http://www.sidefx.com/docs/houdini/basics/config.html

For example if $HSITE= //myNetworkShare/Houdini

You would need this folder structure:

```
//myNetworkShare/Houdini
                        /Houdini16.5
                                    /otls
                                    /scripts
                                    /python2.7libs
                                    /.....
```

Note you can only give $HSITE a single path.